# Creating a Chat Portal

Tags: php, chat

I want to create a chat portal in php. Please help me out in this.
It should be among friends and also among group members.

if I got an example then it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: 1st google result for "php chat" : http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/script-chat-simple_s2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server-side scripting language, which means all the PHP is processed before the page even loads. In order to generate a chat-like environment, you would need to use Javascript to establish an open connection to the back-end (the PHP part). There are many methods to doing this, including polling (timers) and sockets (much more complicated).